# Regex pattern to edit /etc/sudoers file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, awk

I want to remove (uncommnet #) wheel group in /etc/sudoers file so what would be the Regex pattern i should use?

```
#cat /etc/sudoers
....
....
## Allows members of the 'sys' group to run networking, software,
## service management apps and more.
# %sys ALL = NETWORKING, SOFTWARE, SERVICES, STORAGE, DELEGATING, PROCESSES, LOCATE, DRIVERS

## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
# %wheel        ALL=(ALL)       ALL

## Same thing without a password
# %wheel  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL

....
....
```

I want to remove # from following line.

```
...
# %wheel  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
...
```

Comment: you can check the answer by ***Alex G*** in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38849067/modify-etc-sudoers-with-sed. He managed to use `sed` to edit the file and then use `visudo` to check the format before save the changes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You shouldn't edit the `/etc/sudoers` file with any sort of script.  There's a reason for the `visudo` command.  Edits to the `sudoers` file should be rare and well-controlled.

That being said, if your editor for the `visudo` command is vi, you can run something like `:%s/^# %wheel/%wheel/` to uncomment all of the lines what start with `%wheel`.

Or, if you reeeeeeally think it's necessary:

```
sudo sed --in-place 's/^#\s*\(%wheel\s\+ALL=(ALL)\s\+NOPASSWD:\s\+ALL\)/\1/' /etc/sudoers
```

Run it without the `--in-place` first to check the output.  Use it at your own risk.

Comment: I knew! but we have bulk installation and i cant do that by hand. Its just single line edit that's why i am not worried.

Comment: Yeah `\s*` means "zero or more whitespace.  `\s\+` means "one or more whitespace"

Answer (score 7):

The following should work:

```
sed -i 's/^#\s*\(%wheel\s*ALL=(ALL)\s*NOPASSWD:\s*ALL\)/\1/' /etc/sudoers
```

Answer (score 6):

No need to use sed. On centos you can simply create file at `/etc/sudoers.d/`

```
echo 'myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' >> ./myuser
sudo chown root:root ./myuser
sudo mv ./myuser /etc/sudoers.d/
```

This will enable sudo without password for `myuser`. Check this for more information: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375433/etc-sudoers-vs-etc-sudoers-d-file-for-enabling-sudo-for-a-user