# Modify /etc/sudoers with sed

Tags: sed

I'm trying to write a sed program to append `Defaults:user !requiretty` after the line `Defaults requiretty` in `/etc/sudoers`. I tried the following command:

```
sudo sed -i '/Defaults    requiretty/a Defaults:user !requiretty' /etc/sudoers
```

This is working properly, but only if there are 4 spaces between 'Defaults' and 'requiretty'. I want to modify it in order to work with any number of spaces, so I tried the following:

```
sudo sed -i '/Defaults\s+requiretty/a Defaults:user !requiretty' /etc/sudoers
```

I checked the pattern on regexr and it was okay, but still the command does not insert the required line.  Why not?

Comment: don't do it!!!! If you screw this file you will run into serious problems. Instead, use `visudo`.

Comment: Side notes : not a good idea . visudo is best suited for this.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I have to include this into an installer script, and the easiest way is with sed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this;

```
sed '/Defaults.\s\s.requiretty/a Defaults:user !requiretty' /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: This isn't good because its inserting after every line which begins with defaults and ends with requiretty. For example I also had the following line in the file: Defaults:root !requiretty, and it also inserted after this. It should only insert if there are only spaces between.

Comment: Now it is okay. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Working from Mustafa's answer, here's a way to do the same thing with some safety checks added

```
SUDOER_TMP=$(mktemp)
cat /etc/sudoers > $SUDOER_TMP
sed -i -e 's/PATTERN/OUTPUT/' $SUDOER_TMP
visudo -c -f $SUDOER_TMP && \ # this will fail if the syntax is incorrect
    cat $SUDOER_TMP > /etc/sudoers
rm $SUDOER_TMP
```

Comment: so what is `$(mktemp)` for?

Comment: and why use `-i -e` for `sed`?