# Is it safe to edit /etc/sudoers with the Ansible "lineinfile" module?

Tags: ansible

I want to change sudo session timeout according to [this](https://superuser.com/a/149740/775166) answer. I can edit ordinary file:

```
lineinfile:
  path: /etc/sudoers
  regexp: ^Defaults  env_reset
  line: Defaults  env_reset,timestamp_timeout=60
```

But in first line of my `/etc/sudoers` written: `# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.` How to deal with it?
**P.S.**
Despite the fact that the short answer is yes, one must read [Konstantin Suvorov answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46723428/4249707) about right way to do it with `lineinfile` and very interesting [techraf answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46720791/4249707) about possible pitfalls on this way

Comment: visudo only opens the sudoers file in vi... Why do you need it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex pattern to edit /etc/sudoers file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420713/regex-pattern-to-edit-etc-sudoers-file)

Comment: @cricket_007 I want set timestamp_timeout=60 instead of 5 with ansible

Comment: @cricket_007 this pertains to Ansible, not just regex.  Not a duplicate.

Comment: And what's wrong with the current playbook you have shown?

Comment: @Derek Ansible uses the pattern to replace the line in file. The point being (mentioned in the other post) is that you should not modify the file by hand. `visudo` performs additional syntax checks

Comment: @cricket_007 it is not modified by hand- it is being edited by a regex which he has specified? This is exactly the way that Red Hat suggests it be done- http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/lineinfile_module.html

Comment: @ElRuso, ...I agree that the OP's request is silly, but it's very plausibly a corporate-policy-compliance thing (works somewhere with a rule "all edits to /etc/sudoers must use visudo", and trying to automate while staying in compliance with that rule).

Comment: @Derek By hand/Script, same idea - bypassing possible syntax validation was my comment

Comment: @ElRuso, ...so, you've edited your title, but not the text. Could you update the text to be consistent? (The text still says you "must use visudo", and doesn't appear to be a question about safety).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Fixed

Comment: Thank you. I think this is a much better question now. (Editing a question in a way that invalidates prior answers is frowned on here, so there are some questions of decorum in that respect, but... *shrug*).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**It's safe if you've tested the syntax to be correct.**

The point of encouraging `visudo` is to prevent someone from locking themselves out from administering a system by creating an invalid `/etc/sudoers`, whether by a typo or a thinko.

When you're using Ansible to perform an edit, you can test the code performing that edit to do the right thing with your actual config files, environment, and version of `sudo` before you roll it out. Thus, the concerns about people making a typo or a syntax error by hand aren't immediately relevant.

Comment: I really appreciate "thinko". I'm going to start using that.

Answer (score 46):

There's a safenet option for such cases: `validate`.

> The validation command to run before copying into place. The path to the file to validate is passed in via '%s' which must be present as in the example below. The command is passed securely so shell features like expansion and pipes won't work.

If you look at the examples section of [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#examples) module, you'll see exactly what you need:

```
# Validate the sudoers file before saving
- lineinfile:
    path: /etc/sudoers
    state: present
    regexp: '^%ADMIN ALL='
    line: '%ADMIN ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL'
    validate: '/usr/sbin/visudo -cf %s'
```

Comment: This works nicely. I had to make one change to the regex: `'^%ADMIN\s+ALL='`. This allows multiple spaces on the line. Otherwise I was ending up with a duplicate line.

Answer (score 5):

While [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46720626/2947502) defines things correctly and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46723428/2947502) provides a mitigation to potential problems, let's look at your code.

You ask Ansible to (potentially) replace the line defined in the following way:

```
regexp: ^Defaults  env_reset
```

This is clearly a bad practice and if repeated for a parameter other than `Defaults` in `sudoers` file, it is likely to cause a critical problem.

---

Generally `Defaults` is the configuration parameter and `env_reset` is one of possible values.

You cannot assume that the actual configuration file will always contain `^Defaults  env_reset` string.

If there was a different value set, the regexp wouldn't match and you'd end up adding a second line starting with `Defaults`.

---

So the proper way to use `lineinfile` is to use `regexp` argument to match only the configuration parameter, not its value. In your case:

```
regexp: ^Defaults
line: Defaults  env_reset,timestamp_timeout
```

---

The other potential pitfall is that `sudoers` contain sections which should be written in proper order. If the file you modify does not contain the line specified by the regular expression, `lineinfile` will add a new line to the end of the file, where it might get ignored, or result in an error (but that should be discovered by validation), and most likely cause confusion if human looked at the file later. So it might be wise to specify `insertafter` or `insertbefore`.

Comment: ^^This. However - test it **carefully**. If your `insert(before|after)` logic isn't right, it will drop to the end of the file and/or you'll end up with duplicates. Be aware, particularly when working across large numbers of machines and/or systems that have been around a while that 'Jr SysAdmin Elmo' likes to edit the configs, and it might not always look exactly as you expect. Beware simplistic assumptions. ...test, test, test. Throw and error, get your systems consistent, etc; whatever it takes.

Comment: Me? Sorry, you misunderstand me. Was addressing the peanut gallery in general, saying to make sure your logic is correct when you write the regexes. I was agreeing with you, just in the abstract, for cases that don't involve this particular test. You're aces.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I misunderstood, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are missing is that in order to edit `/etc/sudoers` you need sudo-access.  To do this in Ansible, you just need to add the become flag.

```
name: Change Sudo Timeout
become: yes
lineinfile:
  path: /etc/sudoers
  regexp: ^Defaults  env_reset
  line: Defaults  env_reset,timestamp_timeout=60
```

Comment: @cricket_007 correct! That is why you need to add the become flag to Ansible!

Comment: `visudo` has nothing to do with “sudo-access” unlike what you suggest.

Comment: `visudo` runs vi on a copy of `/etc/sudoers`, **and syntax-checks the result before saving**. Its central purpose is the syntax checking, not the privilege escalation; if this answer does not offer said syntax checking, it is off-point.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am not sure that is what the asker is getting at- but we will find out.  This is the way that Red Hat suggests doing it (no mention of validation), so I think this is the right approach.

Comment: Incidentally, I want to say `visudo` honors the `EDITOR` environment variable (thus that the `vi` in the name is a bit misleading), so if you set `EDITOR` to invoke a script that (only) performs your single desired edit, there you are.

Comment: Hmm. With edits, this now appears to be a question about whether the approach is *safe*, not about how to make it work. (If ansible is already running as root, no need for `become`, so it's plausible that it *already does* work).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly editing the `/etc/sudoers` you can place your desired setting into the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory like this:

```
- name: Change sudo session timeout
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/sudoers.d/ssh_session_timeout
    line: 'Defaults  env_reset,timestamp_timeout=60K'
    create: yes
    owner: root 
    group: root 
    mode: "0440"
    state: present
    validate: 'visudo -c -f %s'
```

Comment: Why is it safer? (validation aside, a single file can be validated too, as in [Konstantin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46723428/2947502))

Comment: Actually your proposed solution is much more prone to errors, because you validate only a single file and ignore the fact that errors might occur from conflicting settings across files.