# Ansible regexp match parenthesis

Tags: regex, ansible

I need to match a string `NAME ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL`
However I'm getting stuck with the parenthesis.

I used a website to help me build the expression but am unable to figure it out.
Thusfar I got:
`\sNAME\sALL=\(ALL\)\s\s\s\s\s\s\sNOPASSWD:\sALL` 
However that doesn't get the parenthesis signs...
Also I use a ton of `\s`, which I'm sure there is a better way for?

I'm using the Ansible Lineinfile module to remove the line. 
All help is appreciated, thank you!

EDIT: Just in case, my little playbook added, might be that I do something wrong there:

Hi.

Yeah it matches in all those generators, but for whatever reason I can't get it working in my playbook, am I such an idiot or?

```
- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: Remove user
    lineinfile:
      dest: /etc/sudoers
      regexp: '^.*NAME.*$'
      state: 'absent'
```

Comment: Do you need to match **exactly** that string and nothing else? No flexibility on the number of spaces, etc?

Comment: Use `\s+` instead of the multiple `\s`s. If you want to be more specific, you can do `\s{7}` = 7 times `\s`

Comment: Because if that's the case, the regex you posted should do the trick, check this out: https://regex101.com/r/38xmc2/1

Comment: @GalAbra, maybe OP doesn't want to match if there are too many spaces or line breaks. In that case, `\s+` wouldn't do any good.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat Because this is a pretty specific regex, I assumed it's good enough. But anyway I've already added the `\s{7}` option to my comment

Comment: Hi, no just matching the `NAME` would work as well, but I couldn't get that working so I thought that matching the full string would be easier. Boy was I wrong....

Comment: `regexp: 'avinash\sALL=\(ALL\)\sNOPASSWD:\sALL'`, this is only accepting **one** space between `)` and `NOPASSWD`, so that will not match if there are more, (for instance 7, like in your example).

Comment: @OP Please edit your question and define exactly what is it you want to match...

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat , just matching `NAME` would suffice, but I couldn't get that working so I tried the whole string, as in my post all the way in the top is shown. 

I need to match `NAME ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL`, the easiest way possible, the `NAME` is unique though, so that'd be the best option I guess?

Comment: Which version of Ansible are you using?

Comment: `ansible-2.4.2.0-1.el7.noarch`. Target servers are CentOS 6 & 7, running Python 2.6/7! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You need to escape `(` and `)` with `\`;
- a space in the string is matched by a space in the regular expression;
- you can write the expression between `^` and `$` (or just one of them) to be sure it matches only the exact line (not a commented-out line, for example).

To match the exact line from the question:

```
regexp: '^NAME ALL=\(ALL\)       NOPASSWD: ALL$'
```

---

You can also use `\s` with a multiplier to match a random-length whitespace, for example before `NOPASSWD` string:

```
regexp: '^NAME ALL=\(ALL\)\s*NOPASSWD: ALL$'
```

---

### **BUT**

You are trying to modify `/etc/sudoers` ― take some time to read [Is it safe to edit /etc/sudoers with the Ansible "lineinfile" module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46720411/2947502) and particularly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46723428/2947502).

Comment: Hi @techraf, yeah I'm validating it. I've read some aweful stories with inadequate modifcations of /etc/sudoers.

Question, why `\s*` and not `\s+`?


And is a `\s` not needed between `NAME` and `ALL`?

Comment: I don't know **why**. You asked a question and I answered it. I gave you another option to indicate possibilities. The basic information is: you need to escape `(` and `)` with `\ `, a space is matched by a space, you can use `\s` with a multiplier. How you use the information is up to you.