# Can not make replace working in Ansible

Tags: regex, ansible

I try to replace these lines:

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL

## Same thing without a password
# %wheel        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

By:

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
# %wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL

## Same thing without a password
%wheel        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

My playbook looks like this:

```
  - replace:
      path: /etc/sudoers
      regexp: '^%wheel\s\sALL=\(ALL\)\s\s\s\s\s\s\sALL$'
      replace: '^#\s%wheel\s\sALL=\(ALL\)\s\s\s\s\s\s\sALL$'
    become: yes

  - replace:
      path: /etc/sudoers
      regexp: '^#\s%wheel\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\sALL=\(ALL\)\s\s\s\s\s\s\sNOPASSWD:\sALL'
      replace: '^%wheel\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\sALL=\(ALL\)\s\s\s\s\s\s\sNOPASSWD:\sALL'
    become: yes
```

Updated but also not working for me:

```
  - replace:
      path: /etc/sudoers
      regexp: '^%wheel\s\sALL=\(ALL\)\s\s\s\s\s\s\sALL$'
      replace: '# %wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL'
    become: yes

  - replace:
      path: /etc/sudoers
      regexp: '^#\s%wheel\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\sALL=\(ALL\)\s\s\s\s\s\s\sNOPASSWD:\sALL'
      replace: '# %wheel    ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL'
    become: yes
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Replacement patterns are literal strings except for backreferences. Do not use regex patterns there.

Comment: Updated but still the same issue while my regex seems to match when I use a generator.

Comment: Just might be worth mentioning - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48343037/3832970

Comment: Thanks, replacing \s\s... by \s* seems to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacement patterns are literal strings except for backreferences. Do not use regex patterns there.

Use

```
regexp: '^(%wheel\s+ALL=\(ALL\)\s+ALL)$'
replace: '# \1'
```

And as for the second replacement:

```
regexp: '^#\s+(%wheel\s+ALL=\(ALL\)\s+NOPASSWD:\s+ALL)'
replace: '\1'
```

Here, the `(...)` in the regex patterns define capturing groups and `\1` in the replacement refers to these captured parts. Backreferences allow us to avoid repeating literal strings that are used in the regex pattern in the replacement pattern. `\s+` matches 1 or more occurrences of whitespace chars. You may see [how the second regex works here](https://regex101.com/r/M4yahb/1).